# check string value with xml attribute using javascript xpath

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

this is a part of xml:-

```
<products>
  <product_id value="1">
    <tab_id value="351">
      <tab_name value="test1"/>
      <date value="2013\05\10 12:30:00" />
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
  <product_id value="2">
    <tab_id value="352">
      <tab_name value="test2"/>
      <date value="2013\05\12 12:00:00" />
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
</products>
```

i have following string in one variable:-

```
var result_date="2013\05\10,2013\05\11,2013\05\12,2013\05\13";
```

here i want to check `result_date` every date with the xml file element `date`.
using javascript and xpath.
if `result_date` is match in xml `date` then return there `product_id`
 
i dont know how to check `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss` to `yyyy/mm/dd`  
expected output:-

```
 1,2
```

this both are `product_id` IN MY xml file.
help me out with this.
thansk

Comment: Since JavaScript has no native XPath support: What XPath library are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The xpaht expression you are looking for should be something like:

```
var path="//product_id[contains('" + result_date+ "',substring-before(date/@value ,' '))]";
```

Searching any product_id where the substring-before the blank in date is part of your variable  result_date.

Most browser support "evaluate" (but not IE).

```
var nodes=xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var result=nodes.iterateNext();
while (result)
  {
  document.write(result.attributes.value.nodeValue);

  document.write("<br>");
  result=nodes.iterateNext();
  }
```

If your "result_date" is a const string. You have to be aware of escaping.

```
var result_date='2013\\05\\10,2013\\05\\11,2013\\05\\12,2013\\05\\13';
```